# How to plot SVC classification for an unbalanced dataset with scikit-learn and matplotlib?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, artificial-intelligence, scikit-learn, svm

I have a text classification task with 2599 documents and five labels from 1 to 5. The documents are

```
label | texts
----------
5     |1190
4     |839
3     |239
1     |204
2     |127
```

All ready classified this textual data with very low performance, and also get warnings about ill defined metrics:

```
Accuracy: 0.461057692308

score: 0.461057692308

precision: 0.212574195636

recall: 0.461057692308

  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
 confussion matrix:
[[  0   0   0   0 153]
  'precision', 'predicted', average, warn_for)
 [  0   0   0   0  94]
 [  0   0   0   0 194]
 [  0   0   0   0 680]
 [  0   0   0   0 959]]

 clasification report:
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          1       0.00      0.00      0.00       153
          2       0.00      0.00      0.00        94
          3       0.00      0.00      0.00       194
          4       0.00      0.00      0.00       680
          5       0.46      1.00      0.63       959

avg / total       0.21      0.46      0.29      2080
```

Clearly this is happening by the fact that I have an unbalanced dataset, so I found this [paper](http://sci2s.ugr.es/keel/pdf/specific/congreso/akbani_svm_2004.pdf) where the authors propose several aproaches to deal with this issue:

> The problem is that with imbalanced datasets, the learned boundary is
>   too close to the positive instances. We need to bias SVM in a way that
>   will push the boundary away from the positive instances. Veropoulos et
>   al [14] suggest using different error costs for the positive (C +) and
>   negative (C - ) classes

I know that this could be very complicated but SVC offers several hyper parameters, So my question is: Is there any way to bias SVC in a way that push the boundary away from possitive instances with the hyper parameters that offer SVC classifier?. I know that this could be a difficult problem but any help is welcome, thanks in advance guys.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import numpy as np
tfidf_vect= TfidfVectorizer(use_idf=True, smooth_idf=True, sublinear_tf=False, ngram_range=(2,2))
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split, cross_val_score

import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('/path/of/the/file.csv',
                     header=0, sep=',', names=['id', 'text', 'label'])



reduced_data = tfidf_vect.fit_transform(df['text'].values)
y = df['label'].values



from sklearn.decomposition.truncated_svd import TruncatedSVD
svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=5)
reduced_data = svd.fit_transform(reduced_data)

from sklearn import cross_validation
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(reduced_data,
                                                    y, test_size=0.33)

#with no weights:

from sklearn.svm import SVC
clf = SVC(kernel='linear', class_weight={1: 10})
clf.fit(reduced_data, y)
prediction = clf.predict(X_test)

w = clf.coef_[0]
a = -w[0] / w[1]
xx = np.linspace(-5, 5)
yy = a * xx - clf.intercept_[0] / w[1]


# get the separating hyperplane using weighted classes
wclf = SVC(kernel='linear', class_weight={1: 10})
wclf.fit(reduced_data, y)

ww = wclf.coef_[0]
wa = -ww[0] / ww[1]
wyy = wa * xx - wclf.intercept_[0] / ww[1]

# plot separating hyperplanes and samples
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
h0 = plt.plot(xx, yy, 'k-', label='no weights')
h1 = plt.plot(xx, wyy, 'k--', label='with weights')
plt.scatter(reduced_data[:, 0], reduced_data[:, 1], c=y, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)
plt.legend()

plt.axis('tight')
plt.show()
```

But I get nothing and I cant understand what happened, this is the plot:

[image: weighted vs normal]

then:

```
#Let's show some metrics[unweighted]:
from sklearn.metrics.metrics import precision_score, \
    recall_score, confusion_matrix, classification_report, accuracy_score
print '\nAccuracy:', accuracy_score(y_test, prediction)
print '\nscore:', clf.score(X_train, y_train)
print '\nrecall:', recall_score(y_test, prediction)
print '\nprecision:', precision_score(y_test, prediction)
print '\n clasification report:\n', classification_report(y_test, prediction)
print '\n confussion matrix:\n',confusion_matrix(y_test, prediction)

#Let's show some metrics[weighted]:
print 'weighted:\n'

from sklearn.metrics.metrics import precision_score, \
    recall_score, confusion_matrix, classification_report, accuracy_score
print '\nAccuracy:', accuracy_score(y_test, prediction)
print '\nscore:', wclf.score(X_train, y_train)
print '\nrecall:', recall_score(y_test, prediction)
print '\nprecision:', precision_score(y_test, prediction)
print '\n clasification report:\n', classification_report(y_test, prediction)
print '\n confussion matrix:\n',confusion_matrix(y_test, prediction)
```

This is the [data](http://pastebin.com/0cwiLGG2) that Im using. How can I fix this and plot in a right way this problem?. thanks in advance guys!.

From an answer in this question I remove this lines:

```
#
# from sklearn.decomposition.truncated_svd import TruncatedSVD
# svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=5)
# reduced_data = svd.fit_transform(reduced_data)


#
# w = clf.coef_[0]
# a = -w[0] / w[1]
# xx = np.linspace(-10, 10)
# yy = a * xx - clf.intercept_[0] / w[1]

# ww = wclf.coef_[0]
# wa = -ww[0] / ww[1]
# wyy = wa * xx - wclf.intercept_[0] / ww[1]
#
# # plot separating hyperplanes and samples
# import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# h0 = plt.plot(xx, yy, 'k-', label='no weights')
# h1 = plt.plot(xx, wyy, 'k--', label='with weights')
# plt.scatter(reduced_data[:, 0], reduced_data[:, 1], c=y, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)
# plt.legend()
#
# plt.axis('tight')
# plt.show()

This where the results:

Accuracy: 0.787878787879

score: 0.779437105112

recall: 0.787878787879

precision: 0.827705441238
```

This metrics improved. **How can I plot this results in order to have a nice example like the documentation one. I would like to see the behavior of the two hyper planes?**. Thanks guys!

Comment: `Clearly this is happening by the fact that I have an unbalanced dataset` - I don't find that clear at all based on what you've said. Can you please show us your code and maybe even data?

Comment: What do you get without the SVD and without touching the class_weight parameter? Try to focus on the performance first and then on plotting.

Comment: @Ivlad without using the example from the documentation for unbalanced datasets this is the performance I got: `Accuracy: 0.461057692308
score: 0.461057692308
precision: 0.212574195636
recall: 0.461057692308` this was the best I could do with grid search.

Answer (score 4):

By reducing your data to `5` features with the `SVD`:

```
svd = TruncatedSVD(n_components=5)
reduced_data = svd.fit_transform(reduced_data)
```

You lose a lot of information. Just by removing those lines I get `78%` accuracy.

Leaving the `class_weight` parameter as you set it seems to do better than removing it. I haven't tried giving it other values.

Look into using [k-fold cross validation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.KFold.html) and [grid search](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.grid_search.GridSearchCV.html) to tune the parameters of your model. You can also use a [pipeline](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) if you want to reduce the dimensionality of your data, in order to figure out how much you want to reduce it without affecting performance. [Here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/text_analytics/working_with_text_data.html#parameter-tuning-using-grid-search) is an example that shows how to tune your entire pipeline using grid search.

As for plotting, you can only plot 2d or 3d data. After you train using more dimensions, you can reduce your data to 2 or 3 dimensions and plot that. See [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_separating_hyperplane.html) for a plotting example. The code looks similar to what you're plotting and I got similar results to yours. The problem is that your data has many features and you can only plot things to a 2d or 3d surface. That will usually make it look weird and hard to tell what is going on.

I suggest you don't bother with plotting as it's not going to tell you much for data in high dimensions. Use k-fold cross validation with a grid search in order to get the best parameters and if you want to look into overfitting closer, plot [learning curves](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_learning_curve.html) instead.

All this combined will tell you a lot more about the behavior of your model than plotting the hyperplane.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I remove those lines and I get this exception:`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/user/test.py", line 35, in <module>
    a = -w[0] / w[1]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/csr.py", line 253, in __getitem__
    return self._get_row_slice(row, col)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scipy/sparse/csr.py", line 320, in _get_row_slice
    raise IndexError('index (%d) out of range' % i)
IndexError: index (1) out of range
`. Any idea of how to fix this?.

Comment: @ml_guy - I also commented `w = clf.coef_[0]
a = -w[0] / w[1]
xx = np.linspace(-5, 5)
yy = a * xx - clf.intercept_[0] / w[1]` in order to fix that. I also commented the plotting code.

Comment: Now it works as you said. By the other hand there is a 100 bounty if someone can help me to plot this task.

Comment: sorry @Ivlad i did not understood you. Do you mean to plot this task in 3 dimmentions?...I just want to see a plot of how the hyper planes behave. Thanks for the help!

Comment: just by using cross validation am I preventing overfiting?. The improvement was very strong with this, maybe I am overfiting the algorithm.

Comment: @ml_guy - you can choose to plot it in 2 or 3 dimensions, you cannot plot it in higher dimensions. For this, you need to reduce your data using PCA or another dimensionality reduction algorithm. A cross validation method will not prevent overfitting, but it will help you identify it: if you get good results using cross validation, you can assume your algorithm is good. Otherwise you can assume there's a problem. I am going to add plotting code to my answer in a short while.

Comment: The problem with using dimentionality reduction algorithms is that when I used them, as instance svd with svm I lost performance... probably im doing something wrong... thanks for helping me.

Comment: @ml_guy - you're not doing something wrong, if you reduce your dimensions too much, you'll get worse performance. That's to be expected. You shouldn't reduce them unless you have a good reason, such as to improve execution time or accuracy, the latter not being the case here. I've added more information to my post regarding how you can diagnose issues with your model.

Comment: I am stuck with the plot thing...any idea of how to fix it?. Thanks for the time and help. I guess the bounty is for you.

Comment: @ml_guy - I don't know how else to do it other than they show on the scikit-learn site that I linked to. If that doesn't give good results, then your data just cannot be plotted satisfactorily with reduced dimensions. I guess you can also try Principal Components Analysis (PCA) from scikit, see if that helps.

Comment: @IVlad could you please look into this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/50334915/2508414

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your input correctly you have:

1190 of 5 labeled texts
1409 of 1-4 labeled texts

You may try to do a sequental classification. First threat all 5 labels as 1 and all other as 0. Train a classifier for this task

Second, drop out all 5 examples from your dataset. Train classifier to classify 1-4 labels.

Upon classification run first classifier, if it returns 0 - run second classifier to obtain final label.

Though I don't think that this distribution is really skewed and unballanced (it should be smth like 90% of 5, 10% - all rest, to be really skewed, so that it might be interesting to introduce bias to SVC). Thus I think you might want to try some other classification algorithm since looks like your choice is not suitable for this task. Or maybe you need to use different kernel with your SVC (I assume you use linear kernel, try something different - RBF or polynomial maybe).

Comment: I am using rbf and i tried with multinomial, RF, LR, and with svc it has the best performance.

Comment: thanks for the feedback. Any Idea of how to bias SVC classifier?.

Comment: I beleive klubow provided some useful info below. In scikit-learn you could read about proper way of working with unballanced classed here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/svm/plot_separating_hyperplane_unbalanced.html Keep in mind that you will need to manually tune the class weights for optimal performance, or try to use GridSearchCV to tune them automatically (though you will need to use some specific scoring metrics, otherwise you won't get a good result).

Comment: Thanks for the reference. I dont get what mean: `class_weight={1: 10}` (i.e. `{1: 10}`). For my case it would be:`{1:5}`?

Comment: Why, it is your class labels followed by weight you give them. In your case it will be 5: 10 for example (if your '5' class has this label), if you want to give C parameter a bigger value for 5th class.

Answer (score 2):

As a simple solution, just multiply instances in the smaller classes and balance the number of instances. This works even it seems stupid and it does not require in the rig configuration.

The idea of using this approach is to mimic the behaviour of scaled learning rate for each class regarding its class size. That is, in a gradient based optimization methods, you should scale the learning rate inversely proportional to the class sizes for each class so that you can prevent the model to overlearn some classes against the others.

If your problem is pretty big and you are using batch updates, then instead of booking all the dataset and counting classes, consider only the mini-batch and tune learning rates dynamically regarding number of instances for each class in the mini-batch.

That means if your master-learning rate is 0.01 and in a batch of instances you have 0.4 of them class A and 0.6 of them class B then for each class you need to tune the final learning rate as master_learning rate for class A (that means keep it same), 2/3*master_learning rate for class B. Hence you step wider for class A and reversely for class B.

My choice to go, especially for large problems and augmenting the data for smaller classes by replicating instances or as a more robust choice, adding some noises and variances to replicated instances. In such way, (depending on your problem) you can also train a model which is more robust to small changes (this is very common for especially image classification problems.).

Comment: Do you have any references for the statement that this works? I don't see it working with SVMs.

Comment: In fact I was thinking on do this aproach.... gust copy and paste in order to balance this. What could be the theorical explanation of this aproach?. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: You just balance the number of model updates for each class. Theoretically, it is more meaningful to set learning rate inversely proportional to number of instances per class. By setting the number of instances you just mimic the same behavior in a naive way.

Comment: @IVlad why did you say this doesnt work particulary for SVMs?

Comment: @ml_guy Because SVMs find a large-margin separating hyperplane based on the points you have. Having more of the same points will not change how the hyperplane found looks like.

Comment: And what learning rate for SVCs? I am downvoting this until clarifications are added.

Comment: Before downvoting just try this with a toy problem. Then we can discuss again.

Comment: 1. A toy problem doesn't mean anything; 2. You did not give any arguments or references for your suggestion; 3. It seems like you're suggesting something that scikit-learn allows you to do already in a batter way; 4. Really, what learning rate for SVC? There's no such thing that you can tweak. So really, this is a bad answer regardless of whether or not this works.

Comment: two teachers told me the same thing that  but @IVlad sounds accurate. Any reference of this vlad?

Comment: I add some more comments to my answer, If not satisfied again, that's all for me. By the way, a toy problem is a most thrust worthy way to prove something empirically. Even I do not see any mathematical proof in @lVlad comments then at least you should point out something empirically. If you can other than a toy problem go for it but show something.

Comment: A toy problem is not a trustworthy way of proving something empirically, unless you can prove that it mimics real-life problems in a relevant way. This is usually quite a useless endeavor, since if you can do that, you might as well test your something on those real life problems. I don't know what proof you want from me: I asked for proof for your statements, I did not make any of my own other than that your method is a hack job for what scikit-learn already provides: the class_weight parameter. In SVC you cannot even tweak the learning rate, you need an SGDClassifier for acces to that.

Comment: The proper way to tackle the OP's problem is what me and other people's answers described. I have shown that with references in my answer, while your post still lacks any such references.

Answer (score 2):

You probably already tried to set `class-weight` to `auto`, but I'd like to check for certain.

Maybe experiments with balancing ([oversampling or undersampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oversampling_and_undersampling_in_data_analysis)) can help, some lib for it is already advised by klubow.

Comment: With class-weight auto this was the result:`Accuracy: 0.453846153846
score:0.458315519453
recall: 0.453846153846
precision: 0.205976331361` the metrics go down..

Answer (score 1):

You may want to check class_weight parameter (http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) for SVM classifier 
or 
balance your data (https://github.com/fmfn/UnbalancedDataset/blob/master/UnbalancedDataset.py)

Comment: For this issue what kind of class_weight do I need to set in order to bias the SVM?. Thanks for the help!

Comment: This helped me a lot, any idea of how to plot this?. I just want to be fair for the bounty stuff.